# Start activity and don't finish activity

Tags: android, behavior, activity-finish

I have a splash activity and a MainActivity in which I open some activites:

Resume: SPLAH--> MAIN --> A or B or C and from A or B or C I open more activities

but when I start activity and push the back button from A or B or C the app is finished and I would like the MAIN would be active.

I start activities so:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(this, Listado_mapas.class);

       this.startActivity(i);
        this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.entrada_derecha, R.anim.salida_izquierda);
```

It doesn't work but nevertheless when I open with the same way from B to another activity it backs prefectly. ¿?

Thanks in advance

I don't understand this behaviour !!

why it's running ?

Comment: maybe set A/B/C's parent activity in the manifest.xml to the main activity

Comment: Thanks Isaac, but  I reviewed the code and in the first activity SPLASH i had FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed my code and in the first Activity SPLASH I had FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY.